# how we can sort line by line data from txt file using Apache Spark scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

The log.txt file contains :

```
cat,black,dog,apple,red
zoo,apple,red,blue,green
apple,green,zoo,black,walk
```

My code is :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object ScalaApp {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "Program")

val data = sc.textFile("data.txt").flatMap(line=> line.split(","))
val d1=data.map(_.sorted)
d1.foreach(print _)
 }
 }
```

i want the following result:

```
  apple,black,cat,dog,red
  apple,blue,green,red,zoo
  apple,black,green,walk,zoo
```

but my code give result as :

```
 actabckldgoaelppderoozaelppderbelueegnraelppeegnroozabcklaklw
```

kindly provide any solution!

Comment: " give me errors," What errors? Also, why only select the first and 5th words for sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have solved the problem and want to share with you all too :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object ScalaApp {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "Program")
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt").flatMap(_.split("\n"))
    val lc=data.count().toInt
val d1=data.flatMap(line=>line.split(",").sorted)
d1.foreach(println)
val a=d1.toArray
var loop=0
    for(i<-0 to lc-1){
    println(a(loop)+" "+a(loop+1)+" "+a(loop+2)+" "+a(loop+3)+" "+a(loop+4)+" "+a(loop+5))
    loop=loop+6
 }
 }
 }
```

the data.txt file contains :

```
cat,black,dog,apple,red,cat
zoo,apple,red,blue,green,cat
apple,green,zoo,black,walk,cat
```

The result is :

```
apple black cat cat dog red
apple blue cat green red zoo
apple black cat green walk zoo
```

And that was the desired output!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to first split by line, then by ","

```
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt")
             .map(word=> word.split(",")).map(_.sorted)
data.collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line defining `d1` to:

```
val d1=data.map(_.sorted)
d1.foreach(println _)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should create an `RDD[Array[String]]` where each element of the `RDD` is an array containing the tokens of a line of text sorted in ascending order:

```
val data = sc.textFile("log.txt").map(line => line.split(",").sorted)
```

Also, be aware that if you do a `data.foreach(println)` the output will go to stdout of the workers, not stdout of the driver.

> but my code give result as :
>
> actabckldgoaelppderoozaelppderbelueegnraelppeegnroozabcklaklw

You're getting that mess because `data` is an `RDD[String]` (because you're doing a `flatMap` instead of a `map`.) So when you do `data.map(_.sorted)` it is going to sort each `String` in `data`, e.g. "apple" will become "aelpp", etc. Use `map` instead of `flatMap`.